# Gaussian Elimination over GF(3)

Tags: field, gaussian, galois-field

I'm trying to implement a gaussian algorithm that would work over Galois Field(3). I've already successfully implemented the algorithm over GF(2) but GF(3) seems a bit more tricky.
My main problem is : when the value of the pivot line i've chosen is 2 (pl = 2) , how can i eliminate a 2 in the column ? My first idea would be to add pl/2 to the 2, but in GF(3), i'm not sure 2/2 = 1.

Comment: In what language are you implementing this? Can you show some relevant code? See [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

2/2 == 1 always, because 1 is the neutral element of multiplication.

In a finite field, though, it's not sure that 2 is the only divisor of 2 that leads to 1.

typically, just use multiplication instead of division to reach a 1; much easier!

Comment: If 2/2 ==1, i guess 0/2 in GF(3) is 0, but what would be 1/2 over GF(3) ?

Comment: who says that division is defined in GF(p) ?

Comment: (well, it **is** defined, but look up the definition)

Comment: also, obviously, 0/x == 0 for all x \in GF(2) \ \{0\} , because x*0 == 0

Comment: If it's not defined, how can i eliminate a 2 if my pivot is 2 ? In gf(3), i'd need to add 1 to 2 in order to eliminate it. But if i divide 2 by 2, i have to divide the whole line by 2,which can contains 0 and 1, and i don't know what 0/2 and 1/2 are. Am i getting everything wrong ?

Comment: Ok i think i'm beginning to understad. So you're saying i have to multiply by 1/2 instead of dividing by 2 ?

Comment: no. not at all. Are you aware what a finite field is?

Comment: I thought i was but i'm not sure anymore, GF(3) only contains 0,1,2 right ? So is it right that 1/2 = 0 ?

Comment: *sigh* no, you don't understand GF(3); GF(3) is a finite field, which means it's a *ring* w.r.t. multiplication. 1/2 = 2, because 2*2 = 1 in GF(3). Remember that division is the inverse of multiplication! You're pretty badly prepared for doing matrix operations on GF(3) if you're not aware of this. Please go and read some basic algebra.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I think i'm going to read some algebra indeed, but to sum up, in GF(3) : 0/2 = 0, 1/2 = 2 and 2/2 = 1 right ?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the pivot `a = 2` in the field `GF(3)`, you need to find the multiplicative inverse of 2 in the Galois field, such that `a * a_inv = 1` in `GF(3)`. So to divide by `a`, you will instead multiply by `a_inv` (mod 3). It happens to be that `a_inv = 2`, but not for the reason that `2/2 = 1` (that's incorrect). For example, in `GF(5)` the inverse of 2 is 3, not 2.

The way to find the inverse of an element in a prime field `GF(p)` is to use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). The algorithm finds integers `d, s, t` such that `d = a*s + b*t = gcd(a, b)`. For prime fields `GF(p)` to find the inverse of the element `a`, you compute `1 = a*s + p*t = gcd(a, p)` and `a_inv = s`. The GCD is always 1 because `p` is prime.

I wrote a Python package [galois](https://github.com/mhostetter/galois) that extends NumPy arrays over Galois fields. It also includes functions for computing the extended Euclidean algorithm, among many other things. Here are examples using `galois`.

Manually find the inverse of 2 in `GF(3)`.

```py
In [1]: import galois                                                                                                                                                                          

In [2]: a, p = 2, 3                                                                                                                                                                            

In [3]: d, s, t = galois.egcd(a, p); d, s, t                                                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: (1, -1, 1)

In [4]: a_inv = s % p; a_inv                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[4]: 2

In [5]: a * a_inv % p                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: 1
```

Manually find the inverse of 2 in `GF(5)`.

```py
In [6]: a, p = 2, 5                                                                                                                                                                            

In [7]: d, s, t = galois.egcd(a, p); d, s, t                                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: (1, -2, 1)

In [8]: a_inv = s % p; a_inv                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[8]: 3

In [9]: a * a_inv % p                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[9]: 1
```

Or you can use `galois` to create the field `GF(5)` and then compute the inverses directly, as the library intends.

```py
In [10]: GF = galois.GF(5)                                                                                                                                                                     

In [11]: GF(2)**-1                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[11]: GF(3, order=5)
```

Linear algebra is also supported, including row reduction (Gaussian elimination), as you mentioned, and matrix inverses.

```py
In [19]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                    

In [20]: GF = galois.GF(3)                                                                                                                                                                     

In [21]: A = GF.Random((4,4)); A                                                                                                                                                               
Out[21]: 
GF([[2, 2, 2, 2],
    [0, 2, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [2, 1, 2, 0]], order=3)

In [22]: A.row_reduce()                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[22]: 
GF([[1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]], order=3)

In [23]: A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A); A_inv                                                                                                                                                       
Out[23]: 
GF([[1, 2, 2, 1],
    [2, 0, 2, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 2, 2]], order=3)

In [24]: A @ A_inv                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[24]: 
GF([[1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]], order=3)
```